# CSharp How to generate/parse multiple XElements from a string

Tags: xml, string, addition, xelement

I have an XElement and I need to add more elements to it from a string. The string  contains multiple xml elements in it that I need to parse. I have tried both XDocument.Load and XElement.Parse but get errors. The contents of the file are as follows:

```
<menu id="a">
  <menuItem keyID="0">
    <command>test</command>
  </menuItem>
  <menuItem keyID="0">
    <command>test</command>
  </menuItem>     
</menu>
<menu id="b">
  <menuItem keyID="0">
    <command>test</command>
  </menuItem>
  <menuItem keyID="0">
    <command>test</command>
  </menuItem>     
</menu>    
<ecs>
  <areas>
    <area longitudeFrom="20.35" longitudeTo="20.37" />
    <area longitudeFrom="20.44" longitudeTo="20.46" />
    <area longitudeFrom="20.22" longitudeTo="20.25" />
  </areas>
</ecs>
```

What is the best way to read all the elements from this string and add them to an existing XElement ?

Comment: And the errors are.....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is the whole file it is normal `XMLDocument.Load` to give you errors. For a XML to be loaded it must have one root like this. If the error is in something else please post the error message

```
<root>
    <menu id="a">
      <menuItem keyID="0">
        <command>test</command>
      </menuItem>
      <menuItem keyID="0">
        <command>test</command>
      </menuItem>     
    </menu>
    <menu id="b">
      <menuItem keyID="0">
        <command>test</command>
      </menuItem>
      <menuItem keyID="0">
        <command>test</command>
      </menuItem>     
    </menu>    
    <ecs>
      <areas>
        <area longitudeFrom="20.35" longitudeTo="20.37" />
        <area longitudeFrom="20.44" longitudeTo="20.46" />
        <area longitudeFrom="20.22" longitudeTo="20.25" />
      </areas>
    </ecs>
</root>
```

Comment: XDocument.Load complains about root element being missing
I have now added a root element but now it says [System.ArgumentException] = {"Non white space characters cannot be added to content."}
And actually the string containing xml is too big so I just posted a sample here.
Is there anyway I can parse it with or without a root element ?

Comment: About the new error are you sure there are no text outside the xml and the xml is valid. On the remark about reading the xml without root i don't think it is possible